# SONAR Violation IllegalType, why it is important to fix it?

Tags: java, sonarqube, rules

I have noticed in SONAR that I have a violation that is called IllegalType in my java Code. I looked for this and in Checkstyle explain about it this :

> Checks that particular class are never used as types in variable declarations, return values or parameters. Includes a pattern check that by default disallows abstract classes.
>
> Rationale: Helps reduce coupling on concrete classes. In addition abstract classes should be thought of a convenience base class implementations of interfaces and as such are not types themselves.

But I don't understand really why is this a problem in my code. If anyone can explain me better maybe with an example it could be great!. Thanks at all.

Comment: Show some code... Explanation: *Helps reduce coupling on concrete classes.*

Answer (score 1):

What Aaron Digulla said in his comments is a good practice for sure. However I also found this IllegalType issue with my own Abstract Classes (instead of interfaces) which don't seem to me to be pretty clear. I understand the benefits of using intefaces insteaf of classes, and I also understand that abstract classes are partially classes (so much more a class than a interface) but I don't see the benefits of this rule, as I can find cases where I can return a concrete class (no abstract) which is a superclass of what I'm actually returning.

Comment: My question was more in order what Manuelarte is talking about in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not all violations that Sonar finds are for everyone. The check `IllegalType` ([docs](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#IllegalType)) tries to make sure you don't use classes that most developers deem "broken" in some way like `Vector` (use `ArrayList` instead).

Other classes shouldn't be used as a return type. Always return `List` instead of `ArrayList`, `Set` instead of `HashSet`, `Map` instead of `HashMap` - that way, consumers of your code don't know any unnecessary details about your implementation. If you find you need to replace `HashMap` with `TreeMap` (or vice versa) in a method, that will be much more simple if you don't have to change all the places as well where this method was called.

Generally, the check isn't a problem as such (your code works) but fixing those will make your code easier to maintain in the future.